# Why does the GFCI protecting my in-floor heat trip when the bath fan is switched on?

Tags: bathroom, floor, heat

I have an under floor heating pad to heat the bathroom floor . It has a thermostat with a built in GFI in it and trips only when you turn off the bath fan . How can I correct this

Comment: Are the bath fan and the heating pad on the same circuit?

Comment: Did this start the day you installed it, or did it develop some time later?

Comment: When we had it installed

Comment: Yes fan lights and pad are on the same cct